# How do I get icons into the bottom row of Desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

On my [Toshiba Radius 15](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/toshiba-satellite-radius-15-6-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-8gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-brushed-metal/4203302.p?id=1219706548818&skuId=4203302), I dragged my taskbar to the top of the screen and am attempting to place an icon in the lower right portion of my screen (where time would be). My DPI settings are currently set to the stock 125%. so I don't think this is a similar issue to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/650435/cant-place-icons-on-the-bottom-row-of-the-desktop-windows-7) but rather an entirely different issue as even with Control Scrolling (Hold control and scroll with a mouse wheel), I still am unable to place anything there.

Any ideas are welcome.